# How can I get a row count from all tables based on specific criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I can get the row count of all tables using this query.

```
    SELECT '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' AS fulltable_name, SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS schema_name, t.name AS table_name,
    i.rows
    FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN
    sys.sysindexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2

**AND
t.name.programID = 4**
```

but I need to count all rows where programID = n
I keep getting the following error when adding the bolded line to the where clause

Cannot call methods on nvarchar.
Any help is greatly needed an appreciated
Andy

Comment: Are you sure the column has name 'name.programID' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table name in your example can not be accessed like a property. It's just a string and not the table itself. I've comprised a solution that may work for you. It feels a little like a hack, but It will get you on your way.

```
DECLARE @Value INT, @Column_Name VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Value = 4, @Column_Name = 'ProgramId'

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Results',N'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #Results

SELECT  '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) + '].[' + t.name + ']' AS fulltable_name, SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AS     schema_name, t.name AS table_name,
i.rows [Row_Count]
INTO #Results
FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN
sys.sysindexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.id AND i.indid < 2
INNER JOIN information_schema.COLUMNS  C ON t.name = c.TABLE_NAME AND SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)= c.TABLE_SCHEMA  
WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = @Column_Name

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SqL = COALESCE(@SqL +' UNION ',' ')  + 'SELECT '''+ fulltable_name + ''', COUNT(*) FROM ' +     fulltable_name +     ' where ' + @Column_Name + ' = ' + CAST(@Value AS VARCHAR(1000))+ ' GROUP BY ' + @Column_Name     + ' '
FROM #Results

PRINT(@SqL)
EXEC (@SqL)

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Results',N'U') IS NOT NULL
            DROP TABLE #Results
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all of your tables in the DB have column "programID"? If so.. try this

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'SELECT ''?'' AS TableName,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ? WHERE programID = 4'
```

**Edit**: This query will skip count the table without column"programID"

```
CREATE TABLE #t (table_name Varchar(500), record_count int)

INSERT INTO #t (table_name,record_count)
exec sp_MSforeachtable '
     IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE name = ''programID'' 
             and object_id = object_id(''?''))
     EXEC(''SELECT ''''?'''' AS TableName,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ? WHERE programID = 4'')'

SELECT * FROM #t
```